# Can't update more than 30 rows in fusion table?

Tags: javascript, sql, google-fusion-tables

I can update 30 rows at a time, but I tried below code to update fusion table, but I can't update more than 30 records. How to solve this problem ?

If there is any restriction in google API - fusion table. How to avoid the fusion table restriction.

While update more then 30 records I am getting below error.

```
503 (Service Unavailable)

Object {code: 503, data: Array[1], message: "Internal error. Please try again.", error: Object}
```

Below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Authorization Request</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function auth() {
            var config = {
                'client_id': '607567025394-rmte05500pvsoj12dsrie1cbei5te506.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables',
                'immediate': false
            };
            gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
                console.log('login complete');
                console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
            });
        }

        function Update_row() {
            //First authenticate user:
            auth();

            //Set Google Development colsole API key
            gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyAnEhw4Y7n5V7bN226wWo0tHs0Bd7jAzxA');

            //Fusion table URL : https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o
            gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v2', function () {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                    var selectQry = "SELECT ROWID FROM 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o WHERE Number = '" + i + "'";

                    gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: selectQry }).execute(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);

                        //To get ROWID:
                        var getRowID = response["rows"][0][0];


                        //Update Fusion Table values - Based on selecred ROWID values :
                        var updateQry = "UPDATE 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o SET col2 = 'aaa', col3='2015/01/01' WHERE ROWID = '" + getRowID + "'";
                        gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: updateQry }).execute(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="Update_row();">Update Fusion Table Rows</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 50 same queries and this is not good solution. This can be cause that google tables response with this error. You should use sql construction `WHERE BETWEEN X and Y`.

In your case better solution is:

```
var selectQry = "SELECT ROWID FROM 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o WHERE Number BEETWEN 1 and 50";
```

instead of

```
var selectQry = "SELECT ROWID FROM 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o WHERE Number = '" + i + "'";
```

This query returns result in array. And after that you can just work with this array.

Also you execute `UPDATE` many times. Best solution execute this one time for all rows which you select. So you should you use `WHERE ROWID IN (id1,id2,id3,...,idn)`.

In you case you should prepare your query like this:

```
var updateQry = "UPDATE 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o SET col2 = 'aaa', col3='2015/01/01' WHERE ROWID IN (id1,id2,id3,...,idn)";
```

instead of

```
var updateQry = "UPDATE 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o SET col2 = 'aaa', col3='2015/01/01' WHERE ROWID = '" + getRowID + "'";
```

Comment: I can select more than 30 records. But I can't update more than 30 rows. How to update more then 30 records at a time.

Comment: @Vickram make changes for ```UPDATE``` query many records at the time.

Comment: I tried below query to update rows into fusion table :                             var updateQry = "UPDATE 1Nt5_KO4XpwyPRhSbZExc43yftWwKnUlnuO8xESa5 SET col2 = 'aaa', col3='2015/01/01' WHERE ROWID IN (1001)";   I am getting below error : Object {code: 400, data: Array[1], message: "Invalid query: Parse error near 'IN' (line 1, position 97).", error: Object}

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting your quota. See [the docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#quota) about write requests per minute per table.

You should either use some kind of throttling mechanism or the [importRows](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables) method.
If you ask me, the latter is better.

Comment: I already tried using importRows option it's working fine. But my problem is after importRows into fusion table, I would like to update particular rows. using the above shared code I tried to update. Update was successfully. But I can't update more than 30 records. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: If there is any options for update multiple Rows (more than 30 rows) ?

Comment: There's no way around it. What i see in yor code is that you query 50 rows where 'Number' is between 0 and 49. You can delete these rows with 1 query and insert the updated rows in an import rows query. That's 2 write request instead of 50.